# Android : navigation drawer into flyout menu

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

Hi is there any way I can implement present android navigation drawer with drawer layout as fly out menu.

https://www.google.com/design/spec/patterns/navigation-drawer.html#

From the above guide the slide come on top of the activity
I want the whole screen to slide as below

https://github.com/garuma/FlyOutMenu

can some one point me in right direction or any sample library